# How to extract values of a column and create a new column with the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like below, I want to be able to extract all values in the column 'Holiday' that says 'N' and create av new column 'NonHoliday'

```
My_data
        Date Holiday 
        1     Y 
        2     N 
        3     N 
        4     Y 
        5     Y
```

My code

```
My_data['Holiday'] = My_data['Holiday'] == 'N'
```

gives an error message, I wanted something like this

```
Date NonHoliday 
2     N 
3     N
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new_df = My_data.loc[My_data['Holiday'] == 'N']
```

or:

```
new_df = My_data[My_data['Holiday'] == 'N']
```

And then:

```
new_df.columns = ['Date', 'NonHoliday']
```